# Eucalyptus installation

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, eucalyptus

I am trying to install Eucalyptus in a virtual machine. I am using vmware version 9 and Eucalyptus FastStart version 3.1 And the network adapter which I have choose is NAT..

I am having problem with front end installation. This are some details about the problem
Details about my node controller

```
Host name:neel.localdomain
Wired connection:
Ip address:192.168.211.11
NetMask:24
Gateway:192.168.211.2
DNS Server:8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Wireless conection:
Ip address:192.168.211.12
NetMask:24
Gateway:192.168.211.3
DNS Server:8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Details about my front end
HostName:localhost.localdomain

wired connection:
Ip address:192.168.211.13
NetMask:24
Gateway:192.168.211.4
DNS Server:8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Wireless connection:
Ip address:192.168.211.14
NetMask:24
Gateway:192.168.211.5
DNS Server:8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Public Ip range list:
192.168.211.50-192.168.211.74
```

During node registration process i enter the following ip address 192.168.211.11 to get registered but i get the following error 
ssh:connect to host 192.168.211.11 port 22:no route to host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed(0 bytes received so far)[sender]
rsync error:unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600)[sender=3.0.6]

One more doubt of mine is while installing front end do node controller have to be in on state and also logged in and I am installing both the front end and also cloud controller in different virtual machine but in same laptop is that ok?

Comment: can you tell me in detail????

Comment: what i am trying to do is ..create an cloud application and upload in my own cloud den allow users to use that application and prevent guest to guest attack...so any idea how can one do this ??? what i thought is will create my own cloud in eucalyptus then develop some app using netbeans or eclipse then provide that service to users and den prevent guest to guest attack .....pls help pls

Answer (score 0):

FastStart is intended for use on hardware, if you want to use Eucalyptus in a VM you might want to try [eucadev](https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucadev) although the intended usage is development and testing of Eucalyptus.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to faststart guide:

> https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#faststart-guide/index.html

And yes, I also have installed successfully Eucalyptus from Faststart using VMware workstation.

**Basic idea is to Install Node Controller First & after that starts the Front end 
installation keeping node controller active on the same laptop using VMware.**

Hope this will help to solve your NC registration problem.